# Is there any publications about how to use association rules as SVM feature?

Tags: associations, machine-learning, svm

I'd like to do SVM classification with association rules as features(to detect malwares), is it possible? or is there some publications on this topic?

Comment: Yes, but it would help a lot if you add some information, e.g. what do you consider as an outcome for your classification task?

Comment: @chl I'd like the outcome be whether an executable program is malware or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some articles that might be (or not) relevant to your question:

1. Keivan Kianmehr and Reda Alhajj. Effective Classification by Integrating Support Vector Machine and Association Rule Mining. *Lecture Notes in Computer Science*, 2006, Volume 4224/2006, 920-927
2. He et al. [Extracting rule from SVM based on association rules](http://books.google.fr/books?id=mFj9MBCYekcC&pg=PA238&lpg=PA238&dq=svm%20based%20on%20association%20rules&source=bl&ots=Rs5ko5sXW2&sig=vRcV7NhQdYh0kkkGJWF1PrI4OD0&hl=fr&ei=6JLqTYiZHJSHhQf78qC6Bg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=svm%20based%20on%20association%20rules&f=false), in Rule extraction from support vector machines (Ed. J Diederich), Springer, 2008

You may also want to google articles related to what is known as *associative classification*.